# I want to add array in my mongodb data in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, laravel

Hi I am new to mongodb..
My problem is to append array in mongodb  data

**My array**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5864f61111115810fc011111"),
    "estimate" : {
        "estimate_id" : 1122332,
        "source_data" : {
            "1" : {
                "test":"test"
            }
        }
    },
    "updated_at" : ISODate("1970-01-15T10:47:01.399Z"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("1970-01-15T10:41:56.623Z")
}
```

I want to add array in `source_data` like bellow

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5864f61111115810fc011111"),
    "estimate" : {
        "estimate_id" : 1122332,
        "source_data" : {
            "1" : {
                "name":"nikhil"
            },
            "2" : {
                "name":"nikhil"
            }
        }
    },
    "updated_at" : ISODate("1970-01-15T10:47:01.399Z"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("1970-01-15T10:41:56.623Z")
}
```

I have tried below code but not working

```
$data = array("2"=>array("name":"nikhil"));
$sourcing = Sourcing::find('5864f61111115810fc011111');//return mongo data
$sourcing->put('estimate.source_data.2',$data );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To append one or more values to an array, the following which uses the **[`push()`](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/blob/master/tests/QueryBuilderTest.php#L203)** method should work for you:

```
$data = array('name' => 'nikhil');
Sourcing::find('5864f61111115810fc011111')->push('estimate.source_data', $data);
```